# Why optical flow equation is under defined?

Tags: computer-vision, opticalflow

I am a newbie to computer vision and while going through the optical flow topic I had a conceptual doubt.
Why cant optical flow be calculated by taking difference between x and y values of the pixels in two consecutive frames and dividing them by time between two frames?
For example, pixel in image moves from (0,0) to (1,1) in 2 consecutive frame which can be matched using brightness constancy assumption. And by knowing the frame rate one can find out u and v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically you can see that it's underconstrained by looking at the Estimation section in http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow

This is referred to as the aperture problem.  You can google on this for more discussion, or see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_perception#The_aperture_problem for an animated example.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question with a reference [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44400-tutorial-and-toolbox-on-real-time-optical-flow/content/tutorialOpticalFlowPart1_v1.053_release/ApertureIllustration.m), which then got deleted because it was only a link. The reason i shared this code is because it provides an interactive way to get intuition about the aperture problem. The reason i provided a link was because of the code size... but if this is how the editors wants it, then so be it, find the entire function at the end of this message. Use the function most simply in Matlab as:

```
ApertureIllustration;
```

... The full size code I wanted to share with a link only:

```
% Author: Stefan Karlsson, Josef Bigun, 2014

function ApertureIllustration(type)
%interactive visualization of the aperture problem in optical flow
%estimation. This script animates a pattern of horizontal smooth bars within 
% the support of a large disk. The pattern is in a circular motion pattern.
% a smaller apperture is present in the middle of the image. The
% only view the user gets is through the aperture, except for a periodic
% reveal of the scene
% input "type":
% 'regular' , [default] circular aperture, single motion
% 'barber'  , rectangular aperture, barberpole illusion
% 'multiple', circular aperture, multiple motions
% 'color'   , circular aperture, multiple motions in seperate color channels
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The script supports the following interface:
% MOUSE: 
% click to enable mouse move of aperture, mouse scroll to change aperture
% radius
% KEYBOARD:
% Arrow Keys: move the aperture around
% Q/A : Radius of the aperture
% W/S : the fuzziness of the boundary(higher values makes it Gaussian-like)
%%%%%%%
if nargin < 1
    type = 'regular';end
if ~isnumeric(type)
    switch lower(type)
        case 'regular'
            type = 1;
        case 'barber'
            type = 2;
        case 'multiple'
            type = 3;
        case 'color'
            type = 4;
    end
end
%widht and height of the image
w = 250;
h = 250;
innerRadius = 0.3; %initial radius of aperture
%initial position of aperture, x and y:
innerPx = 0;
innerPy = 0;
minFuz  = 0.01;
%initial fuzziness of aperture:
if type == 2
    innerFuz = minFuz;
else
    innerFuz = 1/10; 
end
fuz = 1/20;      %fuzziness of the moving pattern
%limits in the image are in [-1,+1] for both x and y:
xlims = linspace(-1,1,w);
ylims = linspace(-1,1,h);
[x,y] = meshgrid(xlims,ylims);
p  = linspace(0,2*pi,200);   %used for painting the red boundary of aperture

%When linesmoothing option is on, there is a small bug in the offset of the
%position of linesegments. Fix this with the following added values
bugXVal = (xlims(2)-xlims(1))/2;
bugYVal = (ylims(2)-ylims(1))/2;

%keep track of mouse clicked:
bHasClicked = 0;
%create figure, set up callback functions:
hFig = figure('WindowKeyPressFcn',@localKeyFunc,...
              'WindowButtonDownFcn', @localMousepress); 
hold on
%create the graphics objects, store handles
if type < 4
    hIm = imagesc(xlims, ylims,x,[0,1]);colormap gray(256);
else
    hIm = imagesc(xlims, ylims,zeros([size(x),3]));
end
if type ~= 2
    hCirc = plot(innerRadius*sin(p)-innerPx,innerRadius*cos(p)-innerPy,...
                 'color',[0.6 0.2 0.2],'LineSmoothing','on');
end

axis off;axis image;

t    = 0;  %simulation time
tInc = 0.1; %time increment, simulation
targetFramerate = 15; %target framerate, in real-world time

%as long as the user hasnt shut down the figure, loop:
while ishandle(hFig)
    tic;  %time every iteration to control framerate
    %screener will hold the "characterisitc function" of the aperture:
if type ~= 2
    screener = sig((innerRadius-0.01)-sqrt((x-innerPx).^2+(y-innerPy).^2),innerFuz);
else
    screener = sig(x-innerPx+innerRadius,innerFuz).*sig(-(x-innerPx-innerRadius),innerFuz).*...
               sig(y-innerPy+innerRadius*2  ,innerFuz).*sig(-(y-innerPy-innerRadius*2  ),innerFuz);
end
    t = t+ tInc;
    %the update equation: sigmoidal function for disk boundaries,
    %trigonometric tricks for slowly varying bars
    %centre of the moving pattern is at (cX,xY)
    if type <= 2
        cX = 0.15*cos(t);     
        cY = 0.15*sin(t);
    else % type > = 3
        cX = 0;
        cY = 0.15*sin(t);
    end
    if type < 4
        im = sig(0.84^2-(x-cX).^2-(y-cY).^2,fuz).*(cos(40*(sin(t/100)*(x-cX)+cos(t/100)*(y-cY)))+1)/2;
    else
        im(:,:,2) = sig(0.84^2-(x-cX).^2-(y-cY).^2,fuz).*(cos(40*(sin(t/100)*(x-cX)+cos(t/100)*(y-cY)))+1)/2;
    end
    if type > 2
        t2 = -t-100*pi/2;
%         t2 = t;
        cX = 0.15*cos(t);     
        cY = 0;
%         cX = 0.15*cos(t2);     %centre of the moving pattern is at (cX,xY)
%         cY = 0.15*sin(t2);
        if type ==3
%             newIm = (newIm + backWeight*(250-newIm).*(iix>0)); %apply the background, fixed with hard boundary
            im = (im + 0.7*ed(im).*(1-im).*...
             sig(0.84^2-(x-cX).^2-(y-cY).^2,fuz).*(cos(40*(sin(t2/100)*(x-cX)+cos(t2/100)*(y-cY)))+1)/2);

        else %type ==4
            im(:,:,3) = (1-im(:,:,2)).*...
             sig(0.84^2-(x-cX).^2-(y-cY).^2,fuz).*(cos(40*(sin(t2/100)*(x-cX)+cos(t2/100)*(y-cY)))+1)/2;
        end
    end

    %alpha is used for the periodical unveiling of the full motion pattern
    if type <=2
        alpha =  max(min(((-0.8- 1.55*sin(t*0.35))/2), 0.35),0);
    else % type >=3
        alpha =  max(min(((1.5- 1.55*sin((t+45*tInc)*0.25))/2), 0.35),0);
    end
    if type < 4
        if type == 2
            im = alpha*im + (1-alpha)*(screener.*im + (1 - screener)/2);
        else
            im = alpha*im + (1-alpha)*screener.*im;
        end
    else
        im = alpha*im + (1-alpha)*bsxfun(@times,screener,im);
    end
    %update graphics:
    set(hIm,'CData',im);
if type ~= 2    
    set(hCirc,'XData',(innerRadius-bugXVal)*sin(p)+innerPx+bugXVal, ...
              'YData',(innerRadius-bugYVal)*cos(p)+innerPy+bugYVal);
end
    %restrict frame rate:
    timeToSpare = (1/targetFramerate) - toc; 
    pause(  max(timeToSpare  , 1/100)  ); 
end

%%%%%% nested helper functions
% sigmoidal function for fuzzy rendering:
function out=sig(x,fuzziness)
if (fuzziness == 0)
    out = x > 0;
else
    out= (1+erf(x./fuzziness))/2;
end
end
%%% keyboard event handler, callback function
function localKeyFunc(~,evnt)
switch evnt.Key,
  case 'q', innerRadius = innerRadius +0.01;
  case 'a', innerRadius = max(innerRadius -0.01,0.06);
  case 'w', innerFuz = innerFuz +0.005;
  case 's', innerFuz = max(innerFuz -0.005,minFuz);
  case 'downarrow' , innerPy = max(-1,innerPy -0.02);
  case 'uparrow'   , innerPy = min(1,innerPy +0.02);
  case 'rightarrow', innerPx = min(1,innerPx +0.02);
  case 'leftarrow' , innerPx = max(-1,innerPx -0.02);
end
end

%%%mouse press event handler
function localMousepress(~,~)
mousePos=get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
if max(max(abs(mousePos(1,:))))<1.1
    innerPy = mousePos(1,2);
    innerPx = mousePos(1,1);
    if ~bHasClicked
        set (hFig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseMove,'WindowScrollWheelFcn',@mouseScroll);
        bHasClicked = 1;
    else
        set (hFig, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', '','WindowScrollWheelFcn','');
        bHasClicked = 0;    
    end
end
end

%%%mouse scroll event handler, activated on click
function mouseScroll(~,callbackdata)
   innerRadius = max(innerRadius +0.02*callbackdata.VerticalScrollCount,0.06);
end 

%%%mouse move event handler, activated on click
function mouseMove (~, ~)
mousePos=get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
if max(max(abs(mousePos(1,:))))<1.1
    innerPy = mousePos(1,2);
    innerPx = mousePos(1,1);
end
end

% shadowing function for object partial occlusion. Based on the gradient 
% magnitude, not physically justified, just a visualization hack really.
function out = ed(f)
gg = [0.2163,   0.5674,   0.2163];
dx = f(:,[  2:end end ]  ) - f(:,[1 1:(end-1) ]  ) ;
dx = conv2(dx,gg' ,'same');

dy = f(  [  2:end end ],:) - f(  [1 1:(end-1) ],:);
dy = conv2(dy,gg,'same');

out = ((dx.^2 + dy.^2)/8+1).^(-25);
end
end
```